# Detecting and intercepting linked library dependencies at runtime

Tags: c++, c, unix, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

On a UNIX system is there a simple way to identify whether a dynamic (shared) library depends on other dynamic libraries?

I'm exploring system level APIs such as `dlopen` and friends in C and C++. I have a controlled environment where I will be calling `dlopen` and mapping specific functions. The idea is that people will be able to write native plugins to the application (and let us assume for the moment that it is in the author's best interest to make sure the library actually performs the correct function and is not malicious).

However, as a security measure I would like to ensure at runtime that the loaded dynamic library does not link to any other dynamic libraries (the intention being to disallow system calls and only permit functions from the local maths library) - and if it does, don't load it.

Some (long and/or difficult) solutions I've come up with:

- Write a compiler shim that compiles the plugin code with a very specific set of compiler options, and injects some sort of checksum function that can be used to validate that the compiler shim was used.
- Individually slice out all function calls referencing function names I don't want to be used.
- Intercept all syscalls with some linker path trickery.

Is there a simple(r) way of checking dynamic libraries' dependencies?

Comment: maybe that??? 
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128503/finding-dependencies-for-a-compiled-c-program

Comment: Not loading an external library won't necessary prevent system calls from a security point of view. There's way too much a malicious programmer could do in C/C++ without any, if that is your concern. However, the above comment is right, ldd is probably the best option. As far as I know, though, it won't give any hint towards the use of standard library calls, which themselves have much potential for destruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, as a security measure I would like to ensure at runtime that the loaded dynamic library does not link to any other dynamic libraries

Note that a dynamic library can import a symbol *without* explicitly linking to any other dynamic library. For example:

```
int foo() { return open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY); }

gcc -fPIC -shared -o foo.so foo.c -nostdlib
```

Now `foo.so` does not have any `DT_NEEDED` shared library dependencies, yet will still `open` `/etc/passwd` at will.

> (the intention being to disallow system calls and only permit functions from the local maths library) - and if it does, don't load it.

There is so much *wrong* with your intention, it's not even funny.

For a start, you don't need to link to *any* external library to execute system calls directly, it can be trivially done in assembly.

Also, the plugin can find and modify dynamic loader's data, and once it does, it can make your main program do arbitrary things. For example, it can hijack all of your main program's calls into `libc.so`, and redirect them elsewhere.

Once you run untrusted code in your process, it's *game over*.

> solutions I've come up with

None of them have even remote chance of working. Any time you expend on this is time totally wasted.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I would contend however that no time spent on education is time wasted.